# PHP displaying once if repeated data in the field

Tags: php, mysqli

I know this question has been answered similar to the previous asked question. I have tried the solutions but it seems that no matter what way I have tried I still can't get this to work. I am not sure is my coding structure is wrong somewhere.

Currently it is displaying the result as:

```
Cafes (Category)
Starbucks

Cafes (Category)
CoffeeBean
```

But I wanted it to show:

```
Cafes (Category)
Starbucks
CoffeeBean
```

Below is my code:

```
<?php
    $levelArray=array('L1','B1','L2','B2');
        foreach ($levelArray as $i=>$level) {
             $data='';
            $img = "img/".$levelArray[$i];
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='$levelArray[$i]'");
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $data .= '<h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1>
                        <ul class="shop_listing clearfix">
                            <li class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</li>
                            <li class="float_right">'.$row['unit_number'].'</li>
                        </ul>';
        }
        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="'.$img.'" alt="" />
                <div class="content_container">'.$data.'</div>
          </div>'

        }

     ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you want to group stuff by category. To do that, introduce a processing step between query and display. In general going directly from query results to HTML is inadequate for anything except tutorials.

Comment: In addition: `$levelArray[$i]` inside the `foreach()` is unnecessary, since you are extracting the values in `$level`, just use `$level`

Comment: Thanks Royal for pointing that out. Have amended that. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, every time you echo the name of a shop, the category is also echoed, because you're printing the `$row['categories']` and `$row['name']` at the same time.

To fix this, you probably have to separate it, probably by adding a processing step as mentioned by Jon that groups all the shops in the same category together, and echoes the categories once only.

```
$allCategories = array(); $data='';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if(!array_search($row['categories'],$allCategories)){
        array_push($allCategories,$row['categories']);
        $data .= "<h1>{$row['categories']}</h1>";
    }
    $data.= '<ul class="shop_listing clearfix">
                 <li class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</li>
                 <li class="float_right">'.$row['unit_number'].'</li>
             </ul>';

        }
```

Comment: If answering, then show a code example, this is nothing much than Jon's comment :)

Comment: Thanks huey for the help =) It turns out the same issue that I am facing using Ran's solution. =S Meaning it will display the new data in new line instead of displaying together with the same category whenever there is new data input. Example: (Cafes, Starbucks, Coffeebean) (Restaurant, Swensen) [When adding in new data] -> it displays (Cafes, TCC) behind the Restaurant instead of (Cafes, Starbucks, Coffeebean, TCC)

Comment: Try changing your mySQL query to sort the rows by category. That should resolve it. So it's something like: SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='$level' ORDER BY categories

Answer (score 1):

```
$previousVal = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if($previousVal != $row['categories']){
     $data .= '<h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1>
     $previousVal = $row['categories'];
}
     $data .= '<ul class="shop_listing clearfix">
               <li class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</li>
               <li class="float_right">'.$row['unit_number'].'</li>
               </ul>';
}
```

try this one.

Comment: Hi Ran, I have tested it and it worked somehow. I tried to add in 1 more record into the table, it display the latest input data as separated from the previous one. Example, I displayed 2 shop name from Cafe category followed by 1 shop name from Restaurant category. When I input new data into Cafe category, it will display after the Restaurant category instead of showing together with the Cafe category. Hope you get what I mean.